# Got Empty List after click on button

Tags: android, arraylist

I got empty list, even though there are some item in it. May be I not place it in correct place.

**I declare here:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
....
ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> ListOrdres;
....
```

**and then onCreate:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
  ListOrdres = new ArrayList<Pers_Ordre>();
....
```

I have button Scan for scan and put it into my list and button voir to view the list.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_Scan:
            {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_Signe:
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureSignature.class); 
                intent.putExtra(The_CodeDesti, DestiCode);
                startActivityForResult(intent,SIGNATURE_ACTIVITY);
            }
            break; 
        case R.id.btn_Voir:
            {
                DateTxt.setText(LedateFormat.format(Ledate));
                GPSTxt.setText(TempAddr); 
                m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, ListOrdres);
                lv_Ordre.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

and then after each scan, I put the data into my list, when I debug it, the data is put into my list

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
//retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            if (scanContent != null)
            {
                Pers_Ordre OrdreItem = new Pers_Ordre();

                String[] TempOrdre = scanContent.split("_");

                OrdreItem.setLe_CodeClient(TempOrdre[0]);
                OrdreItem.setLe_CodeDest(TempOrdre[1]);
                OrdreItem.setLe_NoOrdre(TempOrdre[2]);
                OrdreItem.setLe_Ordre_1(TempOrdre[3]);
                OrdreItem.setLe_Ordre_2(TempOrdre[4]);  
                OrdreItem.setLe_Date(LedateFormat.format(Ledate));
                OrdreItem.setLe_GPS(TempAddr);
                ListOrdres.add(OrdreItem);
```

but when I click voir to see my list, I got empty list.

my CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> Pers_Ordre_arraylist; 
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> Client_Pers_list) {
        mContext = context;     
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.Pers_Ordre_arraylist = Client_Pers_list;   
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Pers_Ordre_arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Pers_Ordre_arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.NoOrdreView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_NoOrdre);
            holder.Ordre1View = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Ordre1);
            holder.Ordre2View = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Ordre2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Pers_Ordre OrdreItem = (Pers_Ordre)Pers_Ordre_arraylist.get(position);
        holder.NoOrdreView.setText("No Ordre: "+OrdreItem.getLe_NoOrdre());
        holder.Ordre1View.setText("Ordre "+ OrdreItem.getLe_Ordre_1());
        holder.Ordre2View.setText("sur " +OrdreItem.getLe_Ordre_2());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {   
        TextView NoOrdreView;
        TextView Ordre1View;
        TextView Ordre2View;
    }
```

***UPDATE:***
when i put m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after ListOrdres.add(OrdreItem); it crash the programm
but when i put  m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
case R.id.btn_Voir:
            {
                DateTxt.setText(LedateFormat.format(Ledate));
                GPSTxt.setText(TempAddr); 
                m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, ListOrdres);
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lv_Ordre.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

it work, but now i got the other problem, i can scann double item, i wann all item on my list unique

Comment: Just call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `ListOrdres.add(OrdreItem);`

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the code of CustomListAdapter so I can see how you implement it. And after you add or remove data from an Adapter, you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() to notity Adapter that you have changed the dataset.

Comment: thanks you for responding, but i don't think AdapterList Probleme because when i debug it, my ListOrdres is empty

Comment: @user609511 If your `ListOrdres ` is empty when you set adapter how can your list show anything?

Comment: @user609511 if you don't call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after ListOrdres.add(OrdreItem), the Adapter will not know that you have changed the dataset and it should reflect the change to views

Comment: i dit follow your code, but now it crush the programm

Comment: @user609511 please provide me the error stacktrace.